# How do you register a mouse click event handler for the Google+ Hangouts Video Feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus, google-hangouts

I am building a Hangout App and would like to know if its possible to register an event handler to some sort of 'canvas clicked' event.

Is it possible to bind a javascript function to a click event of the canvas used to display the VideoFeed?

I didn't see anything in their API documentation for this and haven't been able to come up with a straight javascript or jQuery solution.  It may be that my Hangout App runs in a separate iframe from the actual video.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The video is not only in a separate iframe, it also runs using a plugin, so events are not available to your hangout app.

The general workaround has been to have your mouse in a box that is under your DOM and track its movement and actions there, but to display a marker on the video using an overlay. This isn't ideal, but generally works fairly well for most applications depending on your needs.

The best example of this is Gerwin Sturm's [Draw Here application](https://github.com/Scarygami/Draw_Here).

Comment: Any chance you have an example of this type of workaround? Your answer is the direction I was starting to take but could not find any samples to build off of.

Comment: I've added a link to Gerwin's example.